# Fragment replacing animation issue

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I use fragments in my application and I try to implement cool animation of fragment replacing.
I use this method for implementing transaction animation.

```
private void setFragmentChangingAnimation(FragmentTransaction ft, int previousFragmentId, int nextFragmentId){
    Log.e(TAG, "Previous = " + previousFragmentId + " Next = " + nextFragmentId);

    if(previousFragmentId == FragmentOptions.ID_SELECT_RESTAURANT_FRAGMENT && nextFragmentId == FragmentOptions.ID_RESTAURANT_MAIN_MENU_FRAGMENT){
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.hold_on_place);
    }
}
```

hold_on_place.xml animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="200" />
</set>
```

enter_from_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="200" />
</set>
```

I want to implement flowing animation: fragment that replaces previous fragment, enter from right corner and flow to left corner. Animation process perfect, BUT, this fragment that flows from right to left places in background, under previous fragment and after animation this fragment that was replaced, bring in front of the container. How can I place fragment which I want replace to front ?

Comment: As far as I've seen, fragment animations do not respect z-order. I encountered more or less the same problem and had to tweak the animation to something where this problem would not be noticeable (i.e. adding an alpha to fade the previous fragment out).

Comment: thank you for your response. I really can't believe that there is no way to fix fragment transaction animation...I still looking for way to implement this animation, thank you, matiash

Comment: Well, if you do figure it out, please let me know. :)